# What is the power / energy of a discrete time constant signal?

Tags: power, signal, signal-processing, energy

I know that this is a very fundamental (and maybe vague) question.

But I'm not sure what period I should use.
I read somewhere that a constant signal doesn't have a fundamental period but is periodic.
So looking at the formulas for calculating energy and power would that mean that a constant signal is an energy signal?

Thank you for your replies, please let me know if you need more clarification. ( I am new to this topic)

Answer (score 6):

Suppose x(t) = K is a constant signal.

The energy which will be dissipated on a unit 1 ohm resistor by x(t) can be computed as:
$$
\begin{align}
E&=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\left | x(t) \right |^{2} dt\\
&=K^2\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }dt \\
&= \infty
\end{align}
$$
The power which will be dissipated on a unit 1 ohm resistor by x(t) can be computed as:
$$
\begin{align}
P&=\lim _{T->\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\left | x(t) \right |^{2} dt\\
&=K^2\lim _{T->\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T }^{T}dt\\
&=K^2\lim _{T->\infty}\frac{2T}{2T}\\
&=K^2
\end{align}
$$

Therefore x(t) has finite power but infinite energy. Which implies a constant signal is a power signal.

Refer: [Energy and Power Signals](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_difference_between_power_signal_and_energy_signal)

Comment: what about for discrete time?

Comment: Apply the discrete time equations. You will get the same result as above. T is irrelavant.

Comment: The first line in the second equation block should integrate from T to -T, right?

Comment: @immibis This is the general formula to calculate energy over infinite length of time.If you put -T to T , then limit T tends to infinity will appear in the formula. Both are equivalent.

Comment: To me, the way it as written seems like it should always evaluate to 0 (any finite value / infinity) or not be defined (infinity / infinity) because the infinity in the limit is not related to the infinity in the integral.

Comment: "Energy of a signal " is a vague term. It depends on time and load. You have to define in which time interval you have to find the energy of a signal. -infnty to +infnty is therefore finding the energy over infinite time interval for an infinite signal. In a finite interval, energy is always obtained as finite.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing)

Comment: https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2013/12/power-and-energy-of-a-signal/

Comment: An example is an infinite cosine wave/sine wave with period T. Its energy is obtained as finite over the time period T(without applying limits).  But if you integrate over infinity limits, you will obtain energy as infinite. But power is obtained as finite and the same value whether you integrate over T period or infinity. That's why it is called a "power signal".

Answer (score 4):

> So looking at the formulas for calculating energy and power would that
>   mean that a constant signal is an energy signal?

- A signal is not a supplier of energy until it starts doing work.
- A volt is not a joule and neither is an amp but
- 1 amp x 1 volt is 1 watt or
- 1 joule per second.